# Snappy Ubuntu Core 15.04 kernel panic (cannot open root device) after `update-grub`

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 15.04

I created a VMDK virtual disk from the **Snappy Ubuntu Core 15.04** image got here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-snappy/vivid/stable/latest/, using it to boot a newly created VM in VMware Workstation Pro 14.

I meant to use this older version to emulate some old device we have.
It boots fine.

However, if I do a `sudo update-grub` (see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWhK2.png)), the next time when it boots, it gets kernel panic because of **VFS: Cannot open root device, "LABEL=system-a" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6** (see picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0trxS.png)).

Picture 1:
[image: How I ran <code>update-grub</code>]

Picture 2:
[image: Kernel panic because root device not being found]

---

A quick research shows that `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has been changed during `update-grub` even if I do not modify `/etc/default/grub` at all.
Picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3VcW.png) shows the original one (the part that contains the menu entry, where `$label` is "system-a"); picture [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otg9K.png) shows the new one.

Picture 3:
[image: Previous menu entry]

Picture 4:
[image: New menu entry that fails]

---

**Update 1 (6/28)**

Attempted `update-initramfs`, no luck.
Still got kernel panic after `update-grub`.

Also, it complains "no such file or directory" for `/boot/config-3.19.0-47-generic`, not sure if relevant (still a lot of output if I turn on verbose mode for this command).

---

**Update 2 (6/28)**

I set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10` and commented out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` in `/etc/default/grub`.
Now I am able to see the hidden timeout and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to show the grub menu.

[image: GRUB menu]

Neither of "system-a" or "system-b" will work.
"Ubuntu" worked at first time; but on next reboot the hidden timeout no longer existed, and it got kernel panic again on "LABEL=system-a".

It seems that in the new `grub.cfg`, "Ubuntu" uses "root=UUID=...", while "system-a" uses "root=LAEBL=system-a".

Note that, before I ran `update-grub`, there was only a "system-a" option in the grub menu.

Answer (score 2):

After looking into the past and post `grub.cfg`, the finding is, when running `update-grub`, there is a function written in `/etc/grub.d/09-snappy` called `get_kernels(...)` that lists all installed kernels in `/boot` and pick the newest one to create the boot menu entry.

The original `grub.cfg` uses `/vmlinuz` and `/initrd.img` which point to `/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic` and `/boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-47-generic`, respectively. However, after running `update-grub`, it picks `/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic.efi.signed`, which does not have a corresponding `initrd.img`. Then the `09-snappy` script **simply ignores** this file not found and did not add the `initrd` command in the generated `grub.cfg`, then the menu entry does not boot.

After deleting `/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic.efi.signed` manually, `update-grub` no longer causes booting problem.

---

**TL;DR**

The signed kernel image `/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic.efi.signed` does not have a corresponding `initrd.img`. Delete it.

---

**New issue:** the `grub.cfg` generated by `update-grub` is replaced by the original one after one successful boot. Not sure why this happens, but it seems to be a separate problem so would not discuss it here.